# Laravel file storage link not found exception

Tags: php, laravel, file, routes, laravel-5.4

Using Laravel 5.4. it's giving me an error of

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

I'm uploading files under storage directory. I can see files in `project-root/storage/app/files`

Also I have created symlink using `php artisan storage:link`.  When I visit the generated link (http://example.com/storage/files/RcDPA5N6FpTWCnnh2w8bQO85id53oAiCeZgITpwB.png)
though, it gives me not found exception.

Also I'm wondering if I'm referring resource then why route is being called.

Comment: The error tells you that the route cant be found. means that laravel tries to get the route from your routes.php file. Try to register the route with the name of the file as variable and try to access that in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command will generate a symlink to `app/storage/public` so the files would need to go in `app/storage/public/files` and then they should be accessible via http://example.com/storage/files/RcDPA5N6FpTWCnnh2w8bQO85id53oAiCeZgITpwB.png.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` creates a foler-link in public directory named storage. which should be accessible. like /js/app.js is accessible similarly storage/file.jpg should also be accessible !!!

Comment: According to the docs and testing locally, I think your `files` folder should be in `storage/app/public`.

Comment: by your last comment i figured that I was using ` $path = $file->store('files');`  instead i should use ` $path = $file->store('public');`
Thanks images are working now